# How to archive completed cards in Trello in the Windows 8 app

Tags: trello, windows, trello-cards

It is very pretty, but I see no way to close a card. Does anyone know?

Comment: This is a question about a desktop application.

Answer (score 4):

Open the card, Right-click in the white-space, in the bottom-left corner, there's the Archive button.

Comment: Doesn't seem intuitive at all. Hope they streamline this.